# Blueimp jQuery-File-Upload - file upload failed: script doesn't call server/php/

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I use Blueimp Jquery-File-Upload (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) for uploading pictures to the server.

**Setting up the demo.**
When I setup this plugin in the root as described in the documentation, all works fine. I even modified some of the code so I can run it on localhost/jsVR/vendor/ 
So far, so good.

**Integration in a existing form**
I modified an existing form and added "basic-plus.html" to the code which results in this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>BOMmeldingen - Veiligheidsregister</title>
        <link rel="icon" 
            type="image/png" 
            href="img/favicon.ico">
        <link id="style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jsVR/css/style.css">
        <link id="easyui-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jsVR/js/jquery-easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
        <link id="easyui-icons-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jsVR/js/jquery-easyui/themes/icon.css">
<!-- scripts to use in the form --> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/jsVR/js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/jsVR/js/jquery-easyui/easyloader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/jsVR/js/jquery-easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header-container"></div>
        <div id="index-container" class="easyui-panel" data-options="{border: true}" style="">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-file-upload/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-file-upload/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">-->
<link id="js/jquery-file-upload-Style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery-file-upload/css/jquery.fileupload.css">
<!--<link id="js/jquery-file-upload-Demo-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery-file-upload/css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css">-->

<style>  
    .lbl{
        width: 30px;
    }
</style>

<!-- include jQuery -->
<!--<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>-->
<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
<script src="js/jquery-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
<script src="js/jquery-file-upload/js/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Canvas to blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
<script src="js/jquery-file-upload/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
<script src="js/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<!-- The XDomainRequest Transport is included for cross-domain file deletion for IE 8 and IE 9 -->
<!--[if (gte IE 8)&(lt IE 10)]>
<script src="js/core/jquery.xdr-transport.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="js/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload processing plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload image preview & resize plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery-file-upload/js/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-video.js"></script> <!-- optional for video uploads -->
<script src="js/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-audio.js"></script> <!-- optional for audio uploads -->
<script src="js/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-file-upload/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!--<div id="dlg" class="easyui-dialog" style="width:900px;height:400px;padding:10px 20px"
                closed="false" buttons="#dlg-buttons">-->
    <div class="ftitle">Details BOM-meldingen</div>
    <div class="container" style="background-color: wheat; padding: 30px;">    
        <form id="frm" method="post" novalidate>
                <div class="fitem">
                        <label class="lbl">Datum:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="datum" class="easyui-datebox" required="true">
                </div>
                <div class="fitem">
                        <label>Melding:</label>
                        <input type="textarea" name="melding" class="easyui-validatebox" required="true">
                </div>
                <div class="fitem">
                        <label>Naam:</label>
                        <input name="naam">
                </div>
                <div class="fitem">
                        <label>Plaats:</label>
                        <input name="plaats">
                </div>
                <div class="fitem">
                        <label>Oplossing:</label>
                        <input name="voorgestelde_oplossing">
                </div>
                <div class="fitem">
                        <label>Eigen actie:</label>
                        <input name="eigen_actie">
                </div>
                <div class="fitem">
                        <label>Gemeld aan:</label>
                        <input name="gemeld_aan">
                </div>
        </form>
<!--</div> end div dialog-box-->

<!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            <span>Add files...</span>
<!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
            <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
        </span>
        <br>
        <br>
<!-- The global progress bar -->
        <div id="progress" class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
        </div>
<!-- The container for the uploaded files -->
        <div id="files" class="files"></div>
        <br>

    <div id="dlg-buttons">
            <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-ok" onclick="save()">Save</a>
            <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-cancel" onclick="javascript:$('#dlg').dialog('close')">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
/*jslint unparam: true */
/*global window, $ */
    $(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = 'server/php/',
        uploadButton = $('<button/>')
            .addClass('btn btn-primary')
            .prop('disabled', true)
            .text('Processing...')
            .on('click', function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data();
                $this
                    .off('click')
                    .text('Abort')
                    .on('click', function () {
                        $this.remove();
                        data.abort();
                    });
                data.submit().always(function () {
                    $this.remove();
                });
            });
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: false,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        maxFileSize: 999000,
        // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
        // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
        // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
            .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
        previewMaxWidth: 100,
        previewMaxHeight: 100,
        previewCrop: true
    }).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
        data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#files');
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            var node = $('<p/>')
                    .append($('<span/>').text(file.name));
            if (!index) {
                node
                    .append('<br>')
                    .append(uploadButton.clone(true).data(data));
            }
            node.appendTo(data.context);
        });
    }).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
        var index = data.index,
            file = data.files[index],
            node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
        if (file.preview) {
            node
                .prepend('<br>')
                .prepend(file.preview);
        }
        if (file.error) {
            node
                .append('<br>')
                .append($('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error));
        }
        if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
            data.context.find('button')
                .text('Upload')
                .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
        }
    }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
    }).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            if (file.url) {
                var link = $('<a>')
                    .attr('target', '_blank')
                    .prop('href', file.url);
                $(data.context.children()[index])
                    .wrap(link);
            } else if (file.error) {
                var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error);
                $(data.context.children()[index])
                    .append('<br>')
                    .append(error);
            }
        });
    }).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function (index) {
            var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text('File upload failed.');
            alert(data.files[index].error);
            $(data.context.children()[index])
                .append('<br>')
                .append(error);
        });
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
</script></div>
        <div id="footer-container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I cannot find anyreason why the file is not loaded to the server.
I added `alert(data.files[index].error);` to catch the error: 'undefined'.
I guess for some reason the script doesn't read server/php/index.php because I added a vardump in this file, but no response.

It may be very obvious where I go wrong, but any help is appreciated.

### SOLVED:

It was obvious indeed.
I changed the url-var in

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = 'server/php/',...
```

with the full path:

```
$(function () {
   'use strict';
   // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
   var url = 'js/jquery-file-upload/server/php/index.php', ...
```

and all goes well. :)

Comment: Don't use "Solved" subchapter to give your answer. Simply answer your own question, if you actually solved the problem. This is Q&A site and questions, that are self-answered by the one, who is asking are most certainly welcome here.

Comment: no offence, but this way of anwering my question is refused :(

Comment: What are you talking about? What is refused? Have you ever [read this text](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)? To cite: "_To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to **ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged**_". No offence on my side, but having reputation of five I'd rather think tiwce before saying someone with reputation of five thousand, that he is wrong.

Comment: Dear Trejder, I never said you wrong. I know that it is preffered way of responding to a question. That why it is called an anwser, isn't it? I've tried to use the awnser-button but my awnser was blocked by a filter, even after following the suggestions of ameliorating the old awnsers. I rather believe in sharing some knowledge than in increasing my reputation, so i added this chapter with my solution for a silly problem, I Know.

Comment: It doesn't matter how it was answer, so long as it was answered.  People get too focused on petty things.